# Magento 2: Plugin before/around/after Interaction

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, plugin, interceptor

In Magento 2, when you create an "around" plugin

```
public function aroundRenderResult(
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    ResponseHttp $response
) {
    //...
    $proceed($response);
    //...      
}
```

you can *proceed* to the next around plugin, culminating with call the actual original method, by calling/invoking the passed in `$proceed` method.  This is a common design pattern, often seen in PHP Frameworks middleware implementations.

However -- it does present some confusion w/r/t to implementation details.  Specifically

> If, in addition to an `aroundPlugin`, an object/class has a `before` or `after` plugin defined, **when** do they fire in relation to the chain of around plugins?

i.e. will all the before methods fire before any around plugin methods fire?  Or will before plugins **only** fire before the final, actual **real** method fires?

The specific problem I'm trying to track down is, I can't seem to get a plugin attached to the dispatch method the a Magento 2 front controller **when Magento's in full page caching mode**.  The full page cache operates by an around plugin that **does not** call `$proceed($response)`.  I've tried digging into some of the code around these plugins and have found the system difficult to reason about without knowing how its intended that plugins work.

i.e. -- the [description on the dev docs page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) appears, in this one specific instance, to be inaccurate.  It's unclear if the documentation is wrong, or if this is a recently introduced bug, if it's an edge case, or if my plugin configuration is wrong.

Does anyone know, by direct observation, or by cultural knowledge, how this prioritization is supposed to work?

Comment: Alan, do you have a rule of thumb when to use `\closure $proceed` vs. `\callable $proceed` in a plugin? The [official doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) only mentions `\callable` and never touches on `\closure`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Plugins are sorted by sort order first, and then by method prefix.

Example: for method with 3 plugins (PluginA, PluginB, PluginC) with following methods and sortOrder:

- PluginA (sortOrder = 10)

  - beforeDispatch()
  - afterDispatch()
- PluginB (sortOrder = 20)

  - beforeDispatch()
  - aroundDispatch()
  - afterDispatch()
- PluginC (sortOrder = 30):

  - beforeDispatch()
  - aroundDispatch()
  - afterDispatch()

Execution flow should be following:

- PluginA::beforeDispatch()
- PluginB::beforeDispatch()
- PluginB::aroundDispatch()

  - PluginC::beforeDispatch()
  - PluginC::aroundDispatch()

    - Action::dispatch()
  - PluginC::afterDispatch()
- PluginB::afterDispatch()
- PluginA::afterDispatch()

Comment: It seems Magento 2 changed this behaviour in later updates https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/#prioritizing-plugins. Now the after plugin methods also have lowest to highest execution order

Answer (score 16):

From the Magento 2 cookbook:

> If there are multiple plugins that extend the same original function,
>   they are executed in the following sequence:
>
> - the before plugin with the lowest `sortOrder`
> - the around plugin with the lowest `sortOrder`
> - other before plugins (from the lowest to highest `sortOrder`)
> - other around plugins (from the lowest to highest `sortOrder`)
> - the after plugin with the highest `sortOrder`
> - other after plugins (from the highest to the lowest `sortOrder`)

Answer (score 1):

For me it should work as:

- if sort order is not defined its equivalent of zero (and this mean that real order is undefined)
- plugins should be sort by order

If you review code of `\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor::___callPlugins()` you can see that plugins called in order of stored in `$pluginInfo` variable.
This information passed form auto generated method in interceptors like

```
public function {method}()
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, '{method}');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::{method}();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('{method}', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}
```

As you see `\Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListInterface` interface and `\Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList` default implementation responsible for plugin sorting. See [_inheritPlugins:152](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php#L152) method

```
/**
 * Sort items
 *
 * @param array $itemA
 * @param array $itemB
 * @return int
 */
protected function _sort($itemA, $itemB)
{
    if (isset($itemA['sortOrder'])) {
        if (isset($itemB['sortOrder'])) {
            return $itemA['sortOrder'] - $itemB['sortOrder'];
        }
        return $itemA['sortOrder'];
    } elseif (isset($itemB['sortOrder'])) {
        return $itemB['sortOrder'];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For me this function have two logical errors:

- `return $itemB['sortOrder'];` should be `return - $itemB['sortOrder']`;
- `return 1;` should be `return 0;`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but is $pluginInfo fully loaded with plugins?  Or is there some lazy loading going on that might impact the behavior?  What does sort order mean for multiple plugins? i.e.  is it "before plugin 1, around plugin 1, after plugin 1, before plugin 2, around plugin 2,  after plugin 2" or "before plugin 1", "before plugin 2, around plugin1, around plugin 2", etc.  The code looks like the later, but "getNext" populating plugin information in a (maybe?) lazy loading way, and how Magento avoid recursion with around make this all unclear, and hard to spot what's a bug, what's a feature.

Comment: Magento sort plugin class not plugin method.

Comment: And list of plugins can be changed, for example, if new aria we be loaded.

Comment: There's some implicit knowledge you have that's not obvious, because "sort the plugin class and not plugin method" doesn't make it clear what the rules for plugin interaction are or should be.

Comment: maybe this link will be useful http://magehero.com/posts/472/magento-2-interception