# Magento 2.2 override extension file

Tags: extensions, magento2.2, plugin, third-party-module

I have a **third-party module** with a file I want to override so I don't loss my changes when upgrading the third-party extension.

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote;

use Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\GiftCard;

class UpdateItem {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * save
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param int $itemId
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $buyRequest
     * @param null|array|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $params
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
     */
    public function aroundUpdateItem($subject, callable $proceed, $item, $buyRequest, $params = null)
    {
        // some code

        return $proceed($itemId, $buyRequest, $params = null);
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::UpdateItem" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem"/>
</type>
```

I tried to add this file to my theme but it doesn't override the third-party file:

> `\app\design\frontend\Mytheme\custom\Vendor_Module\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem.php`

**UPDATE**

`Vendor\Module` and `Vendor_Module` is the third-party module name. So above code is the code I want to override.

**UPDATE 2**

The accepted answer got me on the right track. I did the following:

`Myvendor\Mymodule` and `Myvendor_Mymodule` is a custom module I created.

`Myvendor\Mymodule\etc\di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::UpdateItem" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem" disabled="true" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="Myvendor_Mymodule::UpdateItem" type="Myvendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem"/>
</type>
```

> Myvendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem.php

```
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Quote;

use Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\GiftCard;

class UpdateItem {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * save
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param int $itemId
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $buyRequest
     * @param null|array|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $params
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
     */
    public function aroundUpdateItem($subject, callable $proceed, $item, $buyRequest, $params = null)
    {
        // some code

        return $proceed($itemId, $buyRequest, $params = null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom Plugin class file needs to be located at -

```
$MAGENTO_HOME\app\code\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\UpdateItem.php
```

> **Note:** I'm assuming Vendor\Module is your custom-module's namespace and not the 3rd party vendors namespace.

Additionally, you could try using the `sortOrder` attribute to ensure your custom **Plugin executes before/after** (as desired, per your specific requirements) the Vendor's code.

- This StackExchange answer -  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115117/42207 - should give you a better idea on how the sortOrder param is interpreted by Magento's Plugin system.
- I'd highly recommend reading Alan Storm's very detailed and informative article on Magento 2x's Plugin System -
  http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system/

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Vendor\Module is the third-party module name

Comment: @Cudos - I would highly recommend against making code changes to the Vendor's 3rd party module files as any module updates made by the 3rd party vendor could, essentially, wipe out your custom changes.