# Magento 2: I am curious on how plugin works behind the scene

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 has something called **Plugin**. What I understand, **Plugin** is part of the Magento 2 module's function which allows you to listen to a called **method** in a **class**. Can someone tell me how Magento does this under the hood?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/114139/42656