# Does <sequence> also affect the load order of plugin?

Tags: magento2.2, plugin, sequence

According to magento devdocs

> declares the list of components that must be loaded before the current component is loaded. It’s used for loading different kind of files: configuration files, view files (including CSS, Less, and template files), or setup classes. Note that  does not affect the loading of regular classes (non-setup classes).

So if we define any same plugin(suppose before) for same function and with same order in different module(A and B). If module A depends on module B then should plugin A loads after B?

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, The sortOrder property for plugins determine when their before,
>   after, or around methods get called when more than one plugins are
>   observing the same method.

Let's say following plugins observing the **same method** with the following sort orders.

- **PluginA**   sortOrder  **10**
- **PluginB**   sortOrder  **20**

> The execution flow will be as follows:

- `PluginA::beforeDispatch()`

  - `PluginA::aroundDispatch()` (Magento calls the **first half** until
    callable)
- `PluginB::beforeDispatch()`

  - `PluginB::aroundDispatch()` (Magento calls the **first half** until
    callable)
- `Action::dispatch()`

  - `PluginB::aroundDispatch()` (Magento calls the **Second half** until
    callable)
- `PluginB::afterDispatch()`

  - `PluginA::aroundDispatch()` (Magento calls the **Second half** until
    callable)
- `PluginA::afterDispatch()`

---

> If there's same sortorder in **different module**, then it will be load by
>   module sequence, In your case A is dependent on B.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentA is dependent on Vendor_ComponentB: -->
            <module name="Vendor_ComponentB" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

---

**UPDATED**

More simpler way by [Raphael at Digital Pianism](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114128/magento-2-plugin-before-around-after-interaction/114151#114151) Magento 2 cookbook

If there are multiple plugins that extend the same original function, they are executed in the following sequence:

- the `before` plugin with the `lowest sortOrder`
- the `around` plugin with the `lowest sortOrder`
- `other before` plugins (from the `lowest to highest sortOrder`)
- `other around` plugins (from the `lowest to highest sortOrder`)
- the `after plugin` with the `highest sortOrder`
- `other after` plugins (from the `highest to the lowest sortOrder`)

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#declaring-a-plugin) you have the option to put a **`sortOrder`** element. Sort Order allows you to put a sequence in which a plugin should be called. I haven't tried using the same plugin with the same sort order from a different module. But I think it should work the way how your module depends on each other. In your case, plugin A loads after B.